# How to update a user's data after log in

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express, passport.js

I'm having trouble editing a user's data after the user logs in.
I'm using the MEAN stack(MongoDB, Express, AngularJS, Node.js) stack with Passport.js.
I believe the problem lies with either the express route, the controller function, or possible the form used to submit the edits for the user?

My code is below:

**editProfile.html**

```
        <form ng-submit="update()" ng-controller="ProfileController">
            <br>
            <input type="text" placeholder="New first name." ng-model="firstname">
            <br>
            <input type="text" placeholder="New last name." ng-model="lastname">
            <br>
<!--            <input type="text" placeholder="New Email" ng-model="email">
            <br> -->
            <button type="submit">Update</button>
        </form>
```

**profileCtrl.js**

```
var app = angular.module('app');

app.controller('ProfileController', function($scope, $http, $routeParams, $location, $state) {

// Custom Profile functionality
    $http.get('/api/userData')
        .success(function(data) {
            $scope.user = data; // Expose the user data to your angular scope.
            console.log($scope.user);
    });

    $scope.update = function(id) {
        var id = $scope.user.id;
        $http.put('/editprofile/:id')
        .success(function(data) {
            $scope.user = data;
            console.log($scope.user);
            $state.go('profile');
        });
    }


});
```

**routes.js**

```
app.put('/editprofile/:id', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.isAuthenticated());
    console.log(req.user);
    User.findOne({_id: req.user.id}, isLoggedInAjax, function(err, user) {
        if(err) {
            console.log("Error occured.");
            res.status(400).send();   
        } else {
            if(user) {
                console.log(user);
                user.local.firstname = req.body.local.firstname;
                user.local.lastname = req.body.local.lastname;

            }

            user.save(function(err) {
                if(!err) {
                    console.log("User successfully updated.");
                    res.status(200).send();
                } else {
                    console.log("Error: Could not update user.");
                    res.status(400).send();
                }
            });

        }
    });
});
```

I've been working on this for about a week and a half(embarrasing), but I can't seem to get this form to work.

If I change the `User.findOne({_id: req.user.id},` to `User.findOne({_id: req.params.id},`, I can get the route to work with Postman, but I have to plug in the id to the end of the route like this `http://localhost:9001/editprofile/123123123123123`. I'd like to reference any user in session with this 'update' function however. So I think one possible problem is the way I'm using id in the route call or the controller function for 'update' possibly...

Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.update = function(id) {
    var id = $scope.user.id;
    $http.put('/editprofile/:id')
    .success(function(data) {
        $scope.user = data;
        console.log($scope.user);
        $state.go('profile');
    });
}
```

This doesn't look good. `$http.put('/editprofile/:id')` should be `$http.put('/editprofile/' + id)` for the id to be attached. This way you can use req.params, the same as you did with postman.

`req.params` refers to the route url parameters, `req.user` is attached to the req object by passport after authenticating. You didn't post about your authentication strategy, but `console.log(req.isAuthenticated());` and `console.log(req.user);` should help you decide if it works. If it doesn't and you are using a session based approach, you should take a look into `passport.serializeUser` and `passport.deserializeUser` on how to serialize the user into session.

Comment: Tried making that change to the the controller but still getting a 500 error. ```console.log(req.isAuthenticated());``` and console.log(req.user); equal to ```true``` and the user req.user object respectively.

Comment: Not sure if this would provide some insight, but here: ```       passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
        console.log("Serializing " + user.local.firstname);
        done(null, user.id);
    });

    passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
        User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
            done(err, user);
        });
        console.log("Deserializing.");
    });```

Comment: 500 (if you are not sending it intentionally) is commonly an uncaught exception on your server. I can only see that happening at user.save if you didn't find a user, you're closing the if block too soon. Detailed error messages and the exact results of your console.logs would be great if you need more help.

Comment: This is the error message I'm getting: angular.js:11756 PUT http://localhost:9001/editprofile/undefined 500 (Internal Server Error). I also took your advice and just put the user.save inside the if statement, but got the same error after testing.

Comment: Ok so that's because 'id' is undefined inside your $scope.update function. You can't declare it like var id = $scope.user.id; because you already defined 'id' as a parameter. The way you're calling it $scope.update = function(id) { } should be a function without parameters, like $scope.update = function() { }

Comment: Ok. I removed the id from the parameters, but I'm still getting an error. Does everything look okay, besides that? I can't say I have the experience to detect anything obvious in the code preventing this from working properly.I should also mention that the edit profile page is within a nested ui-view, if this has any connection as to why it's not working.